# PostgreSQL how to find the UID that I just created

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, uuid

I have a problem with PostgreSQL where I can generate a UID for an entry but I don't know how to get this UID out so that I can use it in python.

This is an example of me generating a table:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
create table example(
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    dict JSON NOT NULL
);
```

I use psycopg2 to connect to the database which I can do fine (note that I am omitting the connection code as it is not relevant) . Then execute a query to insert a new record as follows

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO example(id, dict) values (uuid_generate_v4(),'" + json.dumps(data) + "')")
conn.commit()
```

where data is just a sample dictionary.

I want to be able to get the UID I just generated so that I can print it or store it in a file etc. I would prefer to avoid just taking the last record in case multiple users are accessing the database at once.

Does anyone know a way to get this information out from a query?

Comment: `returning id`?

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, led me to a questions that has been asked before so i have flagged this as a duplicate. Thanks for your help.